# How to have a processor intensive function update every tick of the metronome and draw to canvas using web workers?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, web-worker

I have a cellular automaton which we can abbreviate like this:

```
// pretend slow update function called every tick of the metronome
const update = () => {
  let i = 0
  while (i < 10000) {
    console.log(i)
    i++
  }
}
```

Then I have in the main thread a Tone.js "loop" running every tick of the metronome:

```
new Tone.Loop(time => {
  // update() in worker
  // then draw() in main thread
}, '4n').start(0)
```

This loop essentially runs every quarter note at 240 BPM. You can approximate it with setTimeout, but with some extra fancy logic around keeping track of the elapsed time.

My question is, what is the architecture to make sure this draws every tick of the beat and doesn't get out of sync?

If I do this in the web worker system, then I am not sure how it will behave:

```
// main.js
worker.onmessage = () => draw()
new Tone.Loop(time => worker.postMessage('update'), '4n').start(0)

// worker.js
worker.onmessage = () => {
  update()
  postMessage("draw")
}
```

Depending on the async nature of how long the `postMessage` takes in both directions, the draw will come way after the beat potentially.

How do I do this correctly, architecture wise?

Note, the drawing to canvas must happen in the main thread, while the `update` function of the (multiple instances of) cellular automata must be updated all at once in the worker, for performance. Then there will be a `SharedArrayBuffer` to read the final computed values in the `main.js`.

What is the general approach I should take to wire this up?

Comment: Did you intend for `update()` to be an infinite loop? That's pretty processor intensive...

Comment: Haha, fixed that. In reality I have like 10 256x256 celled automata, updated each beat, which is less than every half a second. And it chugs and breaks. It chugs and breaks at just 2 automata in a single thread without the web worker. Barely gets by with just 1 automaton without the web worker. [Scroll to bottom](https://link.band/tune/4) to see an example (and click to play).

Comment: What's the nature of the `update()` function? Can it be parallelized? Is it just math? Can it benefit from something like Typed Arrays, GPU.js, or divide work on more threads?

Comment: Caveat is I don't know anything about Tone, and not much about workers, but isn't the Tone.Loop probably wrapping a worker?  In that case, can you just do the work in the Tone.Loop loop?  To force 0.25sec, you could setup a race condition with a timer (or use Promise.race)?

Comment: What do you want to do if the draw comes after the beat? Deny it? From what I understand you want to preserve the order of the frames, and also show them when they're ready, which should lead to skipping frames if they overlap?

Comment: @Joseph technically yes, the cellular automaton updates in `update` can be put into WebGL and parallelized _somehow_ I am [pretty sure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263359/168199), but I'm not that sophisticated yet and want to keep `update` on the CPU for now. They are using typed arrays, `Uint32Array` and `SharedArrayBuffer`.

Comment: @GuerricP if it takes more than 1 beat to compute `update` on some frame, then update should run 2+ ticks. Like how live TV doesn't get behind if there is lag, it just skips what it missed and continues. But the cellular automaton should have the correct number of update ticks as there were theoretical beats.

Comment: @danh it looks like Tone.Loop (using [ToneEvent](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/blob/a2a13dfe51551fce02bcee6f9c4e440eb936c37d/Tone/event/ToneEvent.ts#L280)) can be used in the webworker itself. It is not implemented using a worker as far as I can tell. Tone.js audio doesn't work in web workers, so I have to play the audio in the main thread. I don't know what you mean about the race condition / solution.

Comment: I guess there is a theoretical limit to how many cellular automata I can have on screen at once. So perhaps an unrelated-to-this-question solution is to have one CA per screen haha.

Comment: Why does the worker have to wait every tick? Is the computation deterministic? Otherwise, what are the variables in there that you need to pass to the Worker? The best might be to buffer a few "frames", and then make your worker produce the following frames as fast as possible, instead of making it wait for the next tick.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to prevent frames from intertwining, preserve their order and do not delay them when they're ready, which means you need to skip those who don't respect the order.

You could pass the time back and forth, then use it to conditionally draw the frame.

```
// main.js
let lastFrameTime

worker.onmessage = ({ data: { time }}) => {
  if(time > lastFrameTime) {
    draw()
    lastFrameTime = time
  }
}
new Tone.Loop(time => worker.postMessage({ action: 'update', time }), '4n').start(0)

// worker.js
worker.onmessage = ({ data: { time }}) => {
  update()
  postMessage({ action: 'draw', time })
}
```

### Edit: You actually need multiple workers per animation

If `update` takes more than 0.25s, then a callback will be queued in the worker before the previous one finishes, which will delay the next `update` call, and so on.

So you actually need multiple workers with some kind of round-robin dispatch between them, and use the code above in order to prevent frame intertwining.

Comment: This gives me some ideas, but in `worker.onmessage`, `time` will always be greater than `lastFrameTime`, since `Tone.Loop` always gives you the next beat time. I think it may need to be more sophisticated in some ways, so `draw` is only called when it can be called (operations have finished and it is synced to _a_ beat), and update is for sure called once every beat.

Comment: Since I realize that `Tone.Loop` could be used in the worker itself, would it be better to use it in a worker instead? I don't know if there is a way to have two loops, one in `main.js` and one in `worker.js` and have them run in sync exactly... That would be ideal, then one thread can do `update`, and the other can do `draw`, but I guess we still need to wait until update is finished. Ugh.

Comment: Is `time` guaranteed to be greater than `lastFrameTime`? I thought your problem was that it might not due to the random execution time of `update`

Comment: OK I got it, the callback queue of the worker will prevent intertwining as the `update` calls will be executed in sequence. Do you confirm that `update` contains only synchronous code?

Comment: I actually think that the event loop will prevent you from doing what you need. If you have a single worker per animation, the event loop of that worker will be a bottleneck and the callback queue will grow forever